# How to quickly switch screen and sound output in Ubuntu 18.04 from commandline?

Tags: bash, sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

I use TV connected by HDMI cable to my laptop.

I want to be able to quickly perform following operations:

- activate TV as main display and switch off the laptop screen,
- switch to the HDMI sound from sound speakers

as well as in reverse direction.

To do so, I wrote following bash script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Switch between (HDMI output + HDMI sound) and (laptop display and laptop sound)

laptopDisp="eDP-1"
laptopSound="sound profile name returned by pacmd list-sinks | grep -e 'name:'"
hdmiDisp="HDMI-1"
hdmiSound="HDMI sound profile name returned by pacmd list-sinks | grep -e 'name:'"

currentDisplay=$(xrandr | grep " connected primary " | awk '{ print$1 }')

if [ "$currentDisplay" == "$laptopDisp" ]
then
    echo "Switching on HDMI, switch off main display"
    xrandr --output $hdmiDisp --auto
    xrandr --output $laptopDisp --off
    pacmd set-default-sink $hdmiSound
    pulseaudio -k
else
    echo "Switching off HDMI screen and set sound from laptop speakers:"
    pacmd set-default-sink $laptopSound
    xrandr --output $laptopDisp --auto
    xrandr --output $hdmiDisp --off
    pulseaudio -k
fi
```

When I run it, the primary screen is changed. Unfortunately, although in the sound control panel I see that sound source was changed, I cannot hear any sound from laptop speakers.

What could be the source of the issue?